# Does AWS TransferUtility.Download() overwrite existing files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A file is being placed into an S3 bucket each month. I need to download it after it arrives to S3. To do this I'm using the AWS TransferUtility.Download() function for this task.

The documentation doesn't indicate if the previous month's file will be overwritten or if the download will fail if a file (with the same name) is already there. Does anyone know how this function will behave?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

So I made a test program to see what the application would do. I found two things. First, to the my original question, I found the program will overwrite the existing file.

Next, before I could download a file, I needed to upload a file. Again, I used the TransferUtility, but the Upload function. This would NOT overwrite the existing file in S3.

So it was interesting to see the different behavior from the upload to the download functions.

Regards,
Mike